# Highcharts: click events for heatmaps

Tags: highcharts

I have a problem with click events on heatmaps: **it works only if you click on a tooltip**, but not on the chart itself. See the demo http://jsfiddle.net/3UWaA/1/

```
    chart: {
        type: 'heatmap',
        events: {
            click: function(event) {
                alert("clicked!");
            }
        }
    }
```

Any suggestions how to fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add the events into a `plotOptions` object.

Like this:

```
plotOptions: {
        series: {
            events: {
                click: function (event) {
                    alert('event!');
                }
            }
        }
    },
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/robschmuecker/3UWaA/3/

Answer (score 3):

Because click event on chart, works in the plotArea, not on the serie. Heatmap serie overlap plotArea, so click event doesnt work. You need to catch plotOptions event on serie / point.

Answer (score 1):

Try inserting the **EVENTS:** under series block and disable the tooltip as below:

```
series: 
    [
    {   name: 'Passed',
        borderWidth: '1',
        borderColor: '#000000', 
        cursor: 'pointer',          
        events:
        {
        click: function ()
        {
        alert('wow');
        }
        },          
        color:'green',          
        data: [[0, 1, ''],[0, 2, ''],[0, 3, '']],
        dataLabels: 
        {
            enabled: 'true',                
            color: '#000000'
        }
    }
   ]
```

So when you click the chart itself,click event will work fine.